# Canvas tag arched text

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

I'm working on some code that curves text along an arc on a canvas, I have the top working as close as I need it to but I also need to add some text to the bottom that curves upwards. I can't work it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, here is a link to the fiddle I'm working on: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dmackintosh88/XzkrE/)

```
var
        text = 'Hello world, Im just JS',
        len = text.length,
        // The coverage of the circle
        angle = Math.PI * .7,
        centerX = 275,
        centerY = 250,
        radius = 200,
        context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
        n = 0;

    // Format the text
    context.font = '40px Arial';
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    context.lineWidth = 2;

    // Save the current state
    context.save();

    // Move our pointer
    context.translate(centerX, centerY);

    // Rotate
    context.rotate(-1 * angle / 2);
    context.rotate(-1 * (angle / len) / 2);

    // Loop over the string
    for(; n < len; n += 1) {
        context.rotate(angle / len);
        context.save();
        context.translate(0, -1 * radius);

        context.fillText(text[n], 0, 0);
        context.strokeText(text[n], 0, 0);

        context.restore();
    };

    // Restore the canvas state
    context.restore();
```

Comment: I thought this was a duplicate, it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to do this. Was two very minor changes.

It involved inverted the translate in the loop and reversing the input string. Perfect

Here is the working code. (notice the two small changes) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dmackintosh88/XzkrE/) is a link

```
var
        text = 'Hello world, Im just JS'.split('').reverse().join(''),
        len = text.length,
        // The coverage of the circle
        angle = Math.PI * .7,
        centerX = 275,
        centerY = 250,
        radius = 200,
        context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
        n = 0;

    // Format the text
    context.font = '40px Arial';
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    context.lineWidth = 2;

    // Save the current state
    context.save();

    // Move our pointer
    context.translate(centerX, centerY);

    // Rotate
    context.rotate(-1 * angle / 2);
    context.rotate(-1 * (angle / len) / 2);

    // Loop over the string
    for(; n < len; n += 1) {
        context.rotate(angle / len);
        context.save();
        context.translate(0, -(-1 * radius));

        context.fillText(text[n], 0, 0);
        context.strokeText(text[n], 0, 0);

        context.restore();
    };

    // Restore the canvas state
    context.restore();
```